# regsvr32 and standard output

Tags: windows, winapi

The `regsvr32` utility suppresses standard output. For example:

```
STDAPI DllRegisterServer(void)
{
    std::cout << "RegisterServer\n";
    return S_OK;
}
```

When executed with:

> regsvr32 my.dll

nothing appears in standard ouput (the successful message box is displayed). Is there anyway to make standard output appear?

Comment: does it also suppress stderr? Just a thought...

Comment: I don't think there's any explicit standard output suppression, more simply, `regsvr32` is a GUI application, and by default its stdin and stdout are not connected to anything.

Comment: @MatteoItalia, that never occurred to me. Thanks.

Comment: @HansPassant, yes I know thanks. Potentially a few lines of output that may not look particularly pretty in a message box but is an option.

Comment: Well, this is only useful for debugging.  The user will always assume Regsvr32 just works without confirmation.  Really debug your code by setting regsvr32.exe as the startup process for your project.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

regsvr32.exe it a Windows Application. It does not own a console.
printf or std::cout won't show any text.

If you insist to show something, you can create console yourself.

call the following lines before your text output.

```
AllocConsole();
freopen("CONOUT$", "w+t", stdout);
```

Comment: +1 and thanks again. FYI, I used `AttachConsole(ATTACH_PARENT_PROCESS);` as the code in your answer created a new console which disappeared immediately.

Comment: @hmjd That's because your DLL register procedure completed. Maybe you could call a MessageBox before exiting DllRegisterServed();

Answer (score 0):

Use with /c

```
regsrv32  yourFile.dll  /c C://log.txt
```

Comment: The command as given doesn't work "The module "c://blah.log" failed to load.". Interestingly, it doesn't error on the /c like other unknown parameters.

Comment: Is this documented? (I know it was posted many years before my comment). Current documentation doesn't show a `/c` flag. https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/249873/how-to-use-the-regsvr32-tool-and-troubleshoot-regsvr32-error-messages